# No se actualiza mi base de datos y no encuentro mi error en la codificación de mi pagina

Tags: php, html, mysql, html5, base-de-datos

Tengo un problema con este sistema que estoy elaborando, mi pagina consta de una conexion a base de datos y al momento de llenar mi formulario no se actualiza nada en la base, esta elaborado con php y html les dejo el codigo de los archivos que uso. Este es el del formulario:

```html
<?php
include("conexion.php");
$con = conectar();

$sql = "SELECT *  FROM cliente";
$query = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-es">
<script src="https://cdn.freecodecamp.org/testable-projects-fcc/v1/bundle.js"></script>

<head>
  <title>Reservacion</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/estilo2.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Lato&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
  <header class="header">
    <h1 id="title" class="text-center">Formulario de reserva</h1>
    <p id="description" class="description text-center">
      Informacion personal del cliente
    </p>
  </header>
  <form id="survey-form">
    <form id="contact" action="insertar.php" method="post">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label id="name-label" for="name">Nombre</label>
        <input type="text" name="NOM_CLIENTE" class="form-control" placeholder="Nombre" tabindex="1">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label id="email-label" for="email">Telefono</label>
        <input type="tel" name="TEL" class="form-control" placeholder="Telefono celular" tabindex="2">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label id="date-label" for="date">Fecha y hora<span class="clue"></span></label>
        <input type="date" name="FECHA_RESER" class="form-control" tabindex="3">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        </div>
        <button name="submit" type="submit" id="submit" data-submit="...Confirmando" class="submit-button">
          Registrar
        </button>
      </form>
    </form>
    <br>
    <a href="lista.php" id="enlace">
      <button id="submit" class="submit-button">Lista de reservaciones</button>
    </a>
    <br>
    <a href="logout.php?cerrar=yes" id="enlace">
      <button id="submit" class="submit-button">Cerrar sesion</button>
    </a>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Este es el de mi conexion a la base de datos:

```html
<?php
    function conectar() {
        $host="127.0.0.1";
        $user="root";
        $pass="root";

        $bd="reservaciones";

        $con=mysqli_connect($host, $user, $pass);

        mysqli_select_db($con, $bd);

        return $con;
    }
```

y este es el codigo que uso para insertar los datos a la DB:

```html
<?php
require("conexion.php");
$con = conectar();

$NOM_CLIENTE = $_POST['NOM_CLIENTE'];
$FECHA_RESER = $_POST['FECHA_RESER'];
$TEL = $_POST['TEL'];

$sql = "INSERT INTO cliente VALUES(NULL, '$NOM_CLIENTE', '$FECHA_RESER', '$TEL')";
$query = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

if ($query) {
    echo "<script> alert('Guardado exitosamente'); </script>";
    Header("Location: reservacion.php");
} else {
    echo "<script> alert('Ha habido un error'); </script>";
}
?>
```

tengo otro formulario que hace lo mismo, con las mismas conexiones y todo solo que con distinto diseño y este si se actualiza. Ya no se que hacer espero me puedan ayudar

Comment: Hola Gerardo, buenas tardes, no se si fue error a la hora de realizar la consulta o si lo tienes de esa forma, pero en el código de insertar a la base de datos tienes únicamente la creación de una nueva conexión, esto es así como lo tienes o el código que tienes sería diferente?

Comment: Una disculpa Eduardo no habia visto que puse el mismo codigo, ahorita agrego el codigo correcto. Gracias por hacermelo saber

Comment: En la base de datos que contienes que tipo de dato tiene el campo que envías como NULL?

Comment: Tengo como NULL el valor de la ID

Comment: El id tiene tipo de dato un int? Adicionalmente tiene la propiedad AUTO_INCREMENT? De ser este el caso omite la declaración del campo NULL en tu sentencia INSERT ya que puede generar conflictos.

Comment: Si es int y tambien tiene el AUTO_INCREMENT, ya omití el NULL y aun asi persiste el problema:(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

el problema reside en que en tu vista de HTML estas utilizando dos etiquetas form una dentro de otra, las paginas de HTML solo deben contener una etiqueta form, en este caso revisé tu código y ese sería el conflicto que presentas.

Tu código:

```
    <form id="survey-form">
        <form id="contact" action="insertar.php" method="post">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label id="name-label" for="name">Nombre</label>
            <input type="text" name="NOM_CLIENTE" class="form-control" placeholder="Nombre" tabindex="1">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label id="email-label" for="email">Telefono</label>
            <input type="tel" name="TEL" class="form-control" placeholder="Telefono celular" tabindex="2">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label id="date-label" for="date">Fecha y hora<span class="clue"></span></label>
            <input type="date" name="FECHA_RESER" class="form-control" tabindex="3">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            </div>
            <button name="submit" type="submit" id="submit" data-submit="...Confirmando" class="submit-button">
              Registrar
            </button>
          </form>
        </form>
```

Manera correcta:

```
<form id="contact" action="insertar.php" method="post">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label id="name-label" for="name">Nombre</label>
            <input type="text" name="NOM_CLIENTE" class="form-control" placeholder="Nombre" tabindex="1">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label id="email-label" for="email">Telefono</label>
            <input type="tel" name="TEL" class="form-control" placeholder="Telefono celular" tabindex="2">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label id="date-label" for="date">Fecha y hora<span class="clue"></span></label>
            <input type="date" name="FECHA_RESER" class="form-control" tabindex="3">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
        </div>
        <button name="submit" type="submit" id="submit" data-submit="...Confirmando" class="submit-button">
            Registrar
        </button>
    </form>
```

En caso de que requieras implementar varias acciones dentro de un form te recomiendo visitar la siguiente documentación [formaction HTML](https://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/att_formaction.asp)

Espero te sea de ayuda.

Comment: Muchísimas gracias, Eduardo, se solucionó con eso. En verdad te agradezco era para un proyecto de escuela y lo tengo que entregar mañana, me salvaste gracias en verdad:)))